# Insert rows in to SQL Server using Visual Studio's Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have created a Database in MS SQL and loaded the Database in my Server Explorer. In my MVC application, I wish to simply populate a single entity inside my database (Customer Name for example), does anyone know how I can send data to the database I have loaded? I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what data access method you want ? pure ado.net/LINQtoSQL/Entityframework ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC MS SQL Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696781/mvc-ms-sql-studio)

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about how to insert data in Visual Studio itself, open Server Explorer, add a Data Connection to your database, expand the Tables node, right click on your table and select Show Table Data. This opens up a screen where you can add data.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to connect and populate one entity you should consider using Code First Entity Framework to drive your model using a plain C# class on the entity.

Scott Guthrie has a post on how to do that: [Using EF Code First with an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx), and Ralph Lavelle has a post that's more specific to MVC and includes migrations in the second part: [Using Entity Framework Code First with an Existing Database (1/2)](http://www.ralphlavelle.net/2012/02/using-entity-framework-code-first-with.html) and [Using Entity Framework Code First with an Existing Database (2/2)](http://www.ralphlavelle.net/2012/02/using-entity-framework-code-first-with_26.html).